# How to filter Azure Auditing

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, audit

I have enabled Azure Auditing in Azure SQL Database, the audit is capturing all activities in the database and store it in Storage Account.
My question is, is there away to configure Azure Audit and filter what to capture and not to capture in the audit?

By default it is capturing DDL, DML, security role, etc and this is tool much information and only wanted to capture security role change, so where do I filter the audit capture as I don't want to filter the data after capture.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I afraid that the answer is no, there isn't a way to configure Azure Audit and filter what to capture and not to capture in the audit.

Azure SQL database Auditing doesn't provide the way to customize the audit actives.

HTH.

Answer (score 2):

Audit logging of an Azure SQL Database can be controlled in more detail by using the [`Set-AzSqlDatabaseAudit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/set-azsqldatabaseaudit) Powershell command.

In your case you might want to look at the `-AuditActionGroup` parameter. One of its accepted values is `DATABASE_ROLE_MEMBER_CHANGE_GROUP`.

The `-PredicateExpression` allows you to specify a `WHERE` clause for what gets logged. I found it very useful to filter out `SELECT 1` queries that some applications do to check for database availability. For example:

```
Set-AzSqlDatabaseAudit -PredicateExpression "statement <> 'SELECT 1'" -ResourceGroupName "myRg" -ServerName "myServer" -DatabaseName "myDb" -LogAnalyticsTargetState Enabled -WorkspaceResourceId "/subscriptions/<subId>/resourcegroups/<rgName>/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/<workspaceName>"
```

Note that the column name is `statement` and not `statement_s` which you see in the logs.